# Attempting to debug JavaScript and jQuery - where to go with this...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Our company site has a JavaScript problem that I'm desperately trying to solve, but really struggling with. My JS skills are good enough to build a site with things like jQuery, but I am not that proficient in debugging - so really appreciate any help.

Seemingly randomly, all JS components (e.g. a jQuery Datepicker) on the page stop working. When force-reloading the page with the error console open, these errors happen about 60% of the time - there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it. The only way to fix the site once this happens is by clearing the cache and reloading.

The Console outputs the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'not'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each'
```

**However**: that's just one example. Other times I will get completely different errors. E.g. a few minutes after submitting this question, I tried again, and got this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

Which again was thrown from jquery.min.js - pretty-printed, line 1453 (third line down):

```
 if (g.call(k) === "[object Array]")
     if (!u)
         e.push.apply(e, k);
```

**I set Chrome to break on all unhandled exceptions**, and this was another exception it caught - on line 3 of the minified jQuery library. Shown below is the pretty-printed version:

```
try {
    b.call(c.documentElement, "[test!='']:sizzle")
    } catch (f) {
        e = !0
    }
```

The actual erroring line begins `b.call[...]`. This works out to line 1904 of jquery.min.js.

- I am using the latest jQuery
- This only started happening recently - after changing nothing!
- The errors happen seemingly randomly
- Usually (but sometimes), no errors are thrown from *my* scripts - e.g. script.js - usually they are thrown from a minified library. It varies each time.
- This seems to happen in all browsers, but more often in Chrome than Firefox

Any ideas where to begin? Unfortunately this is an internal corporate website so providing access is tricky, as we deal with sensitive data throughout the site.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "I want help, but I'm not going to show code". How can we help then? Clear the cache, open the Dev tools -> Network. Then, open your page, and verify that all files are loaded. If the files are loaded correctly, check whether the files are loaded & executed in the correct order.

Comment: You can ignore that error from Sizzle on the `b.call` line, that's a red herring. It's testing whether something that *should* fail actually does fail, which it does on Chrome (and doesn't on Firefox, hence the test).

Comment: @RobW I realise it sounds like that, my apologies - I will try and edit the question and add some more code.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the edit. I have followed your advice - all files load in the correct order - first the document, then the stylesheets, then the JS - beginning with jQuery, then our Plugins, then our custom script file. All seems correct on this front... Just getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` thrown from jquery.min.js... - I have also updated my question to explain this further.

Comment: @JackWebb-Heller It looks like that a script on your page has modified the built-ins, resulting in a very unreliable JavaScript environment. Look for code that modifies `Object.prototype`, `Function.prototype`, `Array.prototype`, ...

Comment: Your tags show google-chrome, does this happen in other browsers also? If only in Chrome could it be linked with a recent version upgrade?

Comment: @HansBPUFAL I am running Chrome Dev, my colleague is running Chrome Beta, and the staff in the main office are running Chrome stable - it happens in all these browsers.

Comment: @RobW Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but I searched the entire codebase for the 3 items you specified. They were all found in `jquery.min.js` several times, in `modernizr.js`, and finally in `jQuery UI` and its `Datepicker` widget. These scripts we have been using in the site since Day 1 with no prior issues with them at all, nor have they been modified since.

Comment: @JackWebb-Heller Eliminate possible causes: Create a new Chrome/Firefox profile. Fixed? No? 2) Disable all modules on your site. Keep adding modules until you see the error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that your page is quite big and the browser tries to execute the js code before the DOM loads completely... probably because you're using in-line javascript code..

That could explain the random errors and the fact that you have errors when you force the reload.

I'd suggest you to put your JS [code inside a dom ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so the js code could be executed without problems..

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The error messages do not match this kind of errors. The error messages indicate that somehow jQuery fails to load correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - just reviewed the source, we have no inline code. Everything is referenced, in the correct order, in `<script src="">` tags.

Comment: Strange how the acceptance of this answer is incongruent with the OP's comment on this answer.